# Why use "or" in Statically Resolved Type Parameters(SRTP) expressions F#?

Tags: f#

```
let inline heterogenousAddBad(value1 : ^T when ^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^U -> ^T), value2 : ^U) = value1 + value2

let inline heterogenousAdd(value1 : ^T when (^T or ^U) : (static member (+) : ^T * ^U -> ^T), value2 : ^U) = value1 + value2

let inline heterogenousAdd2(value1 : ^T when ^U : (static member (+) : ^T * ^U -> ^T), value2 : ^U) = value1 + value2

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let a = heterogenousAdd(5, 6) //work
  printfn "%A" a

  let b = heterogenousAddBad(5, 6) //not work
  printfn "%A" b

  let c = heterogenousAdd2(5, 6) //work
  printfn "%A" c
  0
```

Why need use  or in (^T or ^U) for basic types as int, float and other? User defined types with operator (+) work with function heterogenousAddBad, but basic types not. [Try it](https://repl.it/@AlexanderL2/srtp)